# Export Datagrid values to Excel in flex3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, datagrid, flex3

Datagrid with 3 columns namely Name,Place and Country. In order to export these columns values to Excel sheet by Clicking a Button called 'Export to Excel'. When Click this button, the values in datagrid is exported in excel sheet. If anybody know this, Please give some samples. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file, by making a loop running through each columns and line.
Separate colums with ";" and each line with "\n"

Then, you can import the CSV file into Excel, it should work out of the box.

Comment: But in Datagrid have some values from server, i need to export those values to Excel sheet by clicking Button called 'Export to Excel' placed near to Datagrid. please give me samples

Comment: StackOverflow isn't somewhere you ask someone to do the code for you, it's a help website, where you can improve your skill.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is Russian tutorial translated with Google Translate.](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ru&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fas3coder.blogspot.com%2F2010%2F05%2Fexcel-actionscript-30.html)